# Android query selection difference

Tags: android, sqlite

Using query for my database searching for rows with a specific `number`, I notice that for the selection argument if I use:

```
String selection = NUMBER + " MATCH ?"
String selectionArgs = new String[]{number}

Cursor cursor1 = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
cursor1.moveToFirst();
```

this causes an error, where as if I use:

```
String selection = NUMBER + " = " + number;

Cursor cursor2 = db. query(TABLE_NAME, null, selection, null, null, null, null);
cursor2.moveToFirst();
```

this works fine with no problems. So what's the difference?

Comment: does the logcat say anything helpful?

Comment: It just provides the error message SQL Logic Error or Missing Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the SQLite documentation:

"The MATCH operator is a special syntax for the match() application-defined function. The default match() function implementation raises an exception and is not really useful for anything. But extensions can override the match() function with more helpful logic."

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html